# Print a specific field

Tags: theming, 8

I am working on my template and have gotten it laid out almost how I want.

I have it print the content with {{ page.content }} but what I need is on another part of the page I want to print out a specific field from that same content.

I tried different combinations of twig tags but none worked for me.

```
{{ page.content.field_name }}
{{ content.field_name }}
{{ item.field_name }}
{{ field_name }}
and a few others
```

I tried googling but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Suggestion: enable twig debug and write {{ dump() }}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consult [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!themes!seven!templates!page.html.twig/8), you will see there is a variable `node` that is fully loaded `node` object. so try the following. one of them should work

```
{{ node.field_name.value }}
{{ node.field_name }}
{{ content.field_name }}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I tried that I get the error "Exception: Object of type Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList cannot be printed"

Comment: try in with | raw filter much or _toString

Comment: Thanks for the continued help | raw gives me the same error and __toString makes the page work but still doesn't print the field

Comment: is your field a single valued or multivalued?

Comment: normally your fields should be rendered and processed in node.html.twig or if you still find any issue, I would suggest to use preprocess page function and assign that variable to any custom name. and then print that variable, much like we did in drupal 7

Comment: This works: `{{ node.field_name.value }}`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! I had just found a video from a tutorial series and they showed that {{ content.field }} should have worked it did for them. But  this works!

Comment: I agree with @Shabir, preprocess is the better option, there you can use a field formatter instead of the raw value and you can put a condition, when there is no node preloaded.

Comment: thanks @4k4 I am editing the answer for future reference

Comment: The same logic applies to the `user` variable on the `user.html.twig` template. `user.field_name.value` worked for me, but `user.field_name` didn't.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) you can just use `{{ node.field_name|view }}` for anything (taxonomy terms, paragraphs, etc.) and it will render consistently based on whatever field display settings you have for a given field.

See the bottom item of the [Twig Tweak Cheat Sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x) for an example (and lots of other super-helpful stuff you can do with Twig Tweak).